# Return object after it leaves the browser window in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how i can return an object to its first (0) position once it leaves the browser window. I have an image which will move if you press the button up/down/left/right but it will eventually extend the browser window.

here is the code i already have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">             
       <style>
            img {
                position: absolute;
                top: 500px;
                left: 100px;
            }

            .buttons {
                background-color: aliceblue;
                margin: 0 auto;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function moveBall(direction) {

                var moveDistance = parseInt(document.getElementById('box').value);
                // alert(moveDistance);

                var currentTop = parseInt(document.getElementById('ball').getBoundingClientRect().top);
                // current position of the ball top side
                var currentLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById('ball').getBoundingClientRect().left);
                // current position of the ball left side

                switch (direction){

                    case 'up':
                        var newTop = currentTop - moveDistance;
                        var newTopString = newTop + "px";
                        document.getElementById('ball').style.top = newTopString;
                        // document.getElementById('carRight').style.left="600px";
                        break;
                    case 'right':
                        var newRight = currentLeft + moveDistance;
                        var newRightString = newRight + "px";
                        document.getElementById('ball').style.left = newRightString;
                        break;
                    case 'down':
                        var newDown = currentTop + moveDistance;
                        var newDownString = newDown + "px";
                        document.getElementById('ball').style.top = newDownString;
                        break;
                    case 'left':
                        var newLeft = currentLeft - moveDistance;
                        var newLeftString = newLeft + "px";
                        document.getElementById('ball').style.left = newLeftString;
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/ball.png" alt="Ball" id="ball" width="100px" height="100px">
        <div class="buttons">
            <input id="box" type="number">
            <button id="up" onClick="moveBall('up')">Up</button>
            <button id="right" onClick="moveBall('right')">Right</button>
            <button id="down" onClick="moveBall('down')">Down</button>
            <button id="left" onClick="moveBall('left')">Left</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i know it has something to do with innerWidth & innerHeight but i just dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var 
    height = document.body.clientHeight,
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
```

this will get you the bounding rectangle width, all you have to do is check if you moved outside of it then set the ball position back to `0`.

```
if (newRight > width) newRight = 0;
```

Also, you might want to alter this based on whether you want the whole ball to leave the bounds, its center or simply just to touch the bound then reset.

Comment: thank you very much, i can work with this. i just needed something to get me going